# Flask error: Not being able to add blocks in a simple Flask application

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm trying to create a simple Flask application that uses blocks in the templates. When I try to run this from my CS50 ide, I get a `500 Internal Server Error`. I'm following CS50's Flask Tutorial in the Web Tracks, and it seems that I have written the exact same thing as the video. **Here is my `application.py` file:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    name = request.args.get("name")
    if not name:
        return render_template("failure.html")
    return render_template("hello.html", name=name)
```

**Here are my html pages:**

`layout.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my `index.html` (I won't include the failure and hello pages because they are giving the exact same error and they're pretty much the same thing):

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{ block body %}
        <form action="/hello">
            <input name="name" type="text">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**Error message:**
`jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endblock'.`

Comment: `{ block body %}` --> `{% block body %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a % in line 3 of `index.html`. I looked up [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/templateinheritance/) for reference.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
        <form action="/hello">
            <input name="name" type="text">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: oh, I didn't see that. no problem.

Comment: It's okay! I'll mark it correct anyways for people that have similar issues.